# Preference for C# in adding, multiplication, and division

Tags: c#, division, multiplication, addition, operation

How does C# execute this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int i = 4;

        i *= 4 + 8 / 2;
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
```

This was asked in one of the interview Questions. And I applied BODMAS to it.
But it was wrong. Please Explain.

Comment: Have you tried writing a program to test it?

Comment: The multiplication and division are on different sides of the assignment operator here - I suspect that's what's causing you problems... What was your answer, and why? What have you observed the actual result to be?

Comment: What did you think the right answer was? It had better be 32...

Comment: I take it you are no longer in the interview? Open your IDE, set a breakpoint and go through one F11 at a time

Comment: i = 4 * ( 4 + 8 / 2 ) ?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield You are right

Comment: At the end of the interview where they ask if you have any questions, you should have asked what is the average weight of a laden African swallow in July.

Answer (score 0):

It will be executed equivalent to the following code:

```
int i = 4;
int temp = 8 / 2;
temp = 4 + temp;
i = i * temp;
```

The compiler will shorten it down because it can calculate the constant that is on the right of `i *=`, so in reality it will compile to this:

```
int i = 4;
i *= 8;
```

Comment: may be (i*temp) is a temp by itself too.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by temp, but in IL-code it will temporarily reside on the stack.

Comment: that's what I mean. it will again be hold in temp variable and assign after to i.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, so it means that Actually C# is also following BODMAS Rule.      ` int i = 4;
            i *= 4 + 8 / 2 * 4;
            Console.WriteLine(i);` It gives the result as 80 in c#. and also by BODMAS Rule.

Comment: The result is 32, not 80. `*=` is executed last because it's an assignment operator, not as a multiplication.

Comment: If the interviewer said it was 80, I hope you failed the interview because of this because to be honest, you really don't want to work there.

Comment: Another way to think about it is that `i *= x` is equivalent to `i = i * (x)`.

Comment: 80 is for the this ==>>  int i = 4;

            i *= 4 + 8 / 2 * 4

Comment: But that is a different expression. *That* will be 80.

Comment: So I am confused If C# Follows BODMAS Rule or not, because applying BODMAS is also giving result as 80.

Comment: No it isn't, the problem is that you're not saying **how** you're applying BODMAS. You're just saying you *are*. Where did `* 4` at the end there come from?

Answer (score 0):

i *= 4 + 8 / 2  is executed as:

i = i * (4 + (8 / 2))

That's the correct way of reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Operator precedence is very clear on this: The / is a multiplicative operator and is applied first, then the +. The *= is an assignment operator and is applied last.

So:

```
8 / 2 = 4
4 + 4 = 8
i *= 8;
so i will be 4 * 8 = 32;
```